# Об удвоении Н в страдательных причастиях и в прилагательных

Tags: прилагательные, удвоенные-буквы, причастия

Добрый день! Обращаюсь за Вашей помощью! Может ли кто-нибудь объяснить, почему в суффиксах страдательных причастий прошедшего времени, если они имеют при себе приставки или зависимые слова, пишется два НН, с точки зрения лингвистики? И почему в отглагольных прилагательных при этом пишется одно Н? Почему вообще так происходит? Причастие - это признак предмета по действию, страдательное причастие - испытывает на себе действие со стороны другого предмета. Это имеет значение? С другой стороны, в кратких причастиях, наоборот, пишется одно Н, тогда как в отглагольных прилагательных - два. Удвоение Н указывает на "страдательность", на то, что действие именно совершается кем-то или чем-то? Приставки и зависимые слова указывают на глагольность? 
На Грамме.ру есть примечание о том, что иногда разграничение причастий и прилагательных происходит по смыслу: напр. *топленная печь* и *топленый жир*. в случае с жиром прилагательное *топленый* указывает на постоянный признак (жир всегда топленый), а причастие *топленная* - на временной отрезок времени (печь топили какое-то время). Значит ли это, что два НН - глагольность, испытывание на себе какого-то действия и сближение поэтому с причастием, а одно Н - указание на постоянный признак, сближение с прилагательным?

И в скобках замечу, что ведь далеко не во всех прилагательных пишется одно Н. В то же время в относительных прилагательных в суффиксах **онн** и **енн** пишется два НН. А в суффиксах **ан**, **ян** и **ин** - одно. Но есть исключения... О чем вообще свидетельствует это удвоение?

Comment: Два нн в причастиях объясняется  историческими процессами. Очень интересная статья  по ссылке [О правописании -Н- и -НН- в причастиях и прилагательных](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.68)

Comment: Серж, статья интересная, но  требует внимательного изучения. Но вот прочитав её, можно ли (на уровне понимания простыми пользователями) кратко ответить на вопрос: почему с исторической точки зрения в полных причастиях пишется две  НН, а в кратких - одна Н? Можно ли на уровне современного языка   найти этому семантическое объяснение? В полных причастиях мы пишем НН, усматривая в них обозначение ДЕЙСТВИЯ, в то время как в предложении они чаще являются ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕМ. А в кратких причастиях в роли СКАЗУЕМОГО мы пишем одну букву Н. Вы не усматриваете здесь определенного противоречия?

Answer (score 1):

1) Написание Н или НН само по себе **не имеет смыслового значения**: мы просто записываем нужный суффикс для определенной формы определенной части речи, при этом на стыке морфем возможно удвоение НН.

2) Суффиксы отыменных прилагательных: **АН/ЯН, ИН, Н, ЕНН, ОНН**. Суффиксы полных и кратких отглагольных прилагательных: **ЕН, Н, ЕНН, НН**. Суффиксы полных причастий: **ЕНН, НН**. Суффиксы кратких причастий: **ЕН, Н**

3) Весь смысл орфограммы заключается в том, чтобы **правильно определить** часть речи и правильно записать ее морфемный состав.

4) Основная проблема - это **различение причастий и отглагольных прилагательных** (есть еще отпричастные прилагательные: образованная девушка), а также различение кратких и полных форм.

5) Глагольные формы изначально имеют значение действия, но в особых случаях (при образовании от бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида и при отсутствии зависимых слов) **действие (процессуальный признак) переходит в качество (постоянный признак как результат действия)**:  крашенный в прошлом году пол - крашеный пол). Формальное правило помогает нам различать причастия и прилагательные, но не всегда, например: топленная печь - это печь, которую топили, это причастие со значением действия, суффикс ЕНН.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
Значит ли это, что два НН - глагольность, испытывание на себе 
какого-то   действия и сближение поэтому с причастием, а одно 
Н - указание на постоянный признак, сближение с прилагательным?
```

Аlenka, в целом Вы всё понимаете верно, потому что с помощью суфф.**-нн-**(от инфинитива на-ать-/-ять-пристрел/я/нн/ый),**-енн-**(от инфинитива на -ить или согласный-пристрел/енн/ый)образуются **страдат. причастия**  прош. времени.

Все три условия **-нн-**  несут именно глагольность: 1)приставка придаёт совершенный вид(глаг. признак), 2)-ова-/-ева-/-ирова/ -указывают на  длительность и повторяемость действия, 3) наличие зависимого слова указывает объект или время/место и т.д. **действия.**

Когда причастия **соверш. вида** переходят в прилагательные, они утрачивают глагольность, но сохраняют написание (священный, блаженный,сокровенный постоянный).

Отглаг. прилагательные, образованные от **переходных** глаголов **несов**. вида, имеют значение "тот, который подвергся действию, выраженному основой производящего глагола", их связь с глаголами ещё отчётлива в совр. языке, отсутствие управления(завис. слов) затемняет значение времени, вида и залога. Наоборот, наличие пояснит. слов восстанавливает глагольное значение основы и, следовательно, переводит их в разряд причастий.(Печёный хлеб - печённый в жестяной форме хлеб).

Comment: Спасибо большое! Только тогда "печённый в жестяной форме хлеб", раз есть зависимые слова?..

Comment: Да, конечно, глаза подводят.